Zilog eZ80 and routing I/O accesses of ports 00-FF to the external bus
Classic Z80 production has officially ended according to the news. And anyway, I always wanted to try out eZ80 for my SBC project(s). However there is a fundamental problem in terms of compatibility with eZ80: according to the documents, every eZ80 is for real, part of an MCU which uses all the ports between 0x00 and 0xFF for internal purposes.
I'm not sure if it's possible to turn those accesses off, allowing all I/O port requests to be routed to the outside bus. With Z80 bus compatibility mode, then it's possible (in theory ...) to replace a Z80 with eZ80. However almost all existing Z80 designs relying on I/O port decoding also done for the lower 8 bits of the I/O address which is reserved for the internal registers of eZ80 products. At least with the Z180 it was possible to select 00-7F or 80-FF for this purposes, but it seems, eZ80 is even worse :(
I've tried to contact Zilog about this question but they didn't seem to even understand my question (which is honestly can be the case that my English is not so great ...).

What does the datasheet say about port mapping?

From what I can tell, some members of the eZ80 family have no external I/O, but others do. For example, the datasheet for the eZ80F92/93 clearly states that ports 0x80-0xFF are for internal I/O, and that ports 0x00-0x7F are available for external I/O.
